# Python SqlAlchemy relationships

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, declarative

I'm using Python 2.7.5 and SqlAlchemy 0.9.9 (against an Oracle 11 database) and am trying to figure out how I can create a relationship between two tables where the join value is a string in one table and an integer in another. Here's mockup of my two tables:

```
class BatchInput(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'batchinput'
    batchinput_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_id       = Column(Integer)

class SubBatch(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'subbatch'
    subbatch_id   = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    subbatch_no   = Column(String)
    batch_input   = relationship('BatchInput', 
                                 primaryjoin='SubBatch.subbatch_no == cast(BatchInput.item_id, VARCHAR)')
```

When I run a query to get subbatches I get this message:

```
Internal Server Error, Could not locate any relevant foreign key
columns for primary join condition 
'subbatch.subbatchno = CAST(forgebatchinput.item_id AS VARCHAR)' 
on relationship SubBatch.forge_batch_input.  Ensure that 
referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or
ForeignKeyConstraint, or are annotated in the join condition 
with the foreign() annotation
```

I've tried a couple variations of this adding `foreignkeys` and `remote`, etc., but always get this message. I'm not sure what it's trying to tell me as I do have a primaryjoin specified.

Comment: The relationship that is referred to in your error message is `SubBatch.coatoption`, would that be `SubBatch.batch_input` in your example? Or is there code missing?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, the error I copied directly from my code, which included fields from the actual table. I've edited the message here to reflect the sample classes I've included in the question.